# How to configure osm2po to ignore certain class types?

Tags: postgis, openstreetmap, osm2po

I'm trying to import data using osm2po but am only interested in driving distances, so I'd like to omit all footway, cycleway, steps, etc. in the imported dataset.  How can I configure osm2po to do this ?

The documentation isn't completely clear... I tried leaving the config of wtr.finalMask as only car, which I interpreted it to mean it should only create ways which include the car type.

```
# only convert ways containing one of these flags
wtr.finalMask = car
```

But this is not the case in the resulting dataset.  The ways with class types for just bike, foot, and ferry are all present.

Do I need to just remove these lines from osm2po.config ?

```
wtr.tag.highway.pedestrian =     1, 62, 5,   bike|foot
wtr.tag.highway.track =          1, 71, 10,  bike|foot
wtr.tag.highway.path =           1, 72, 10,  bike|foot
wtr.tag.highway.cycleway =       1, 81, 15,  bike
wtr.tag.highway.footway =        1, 91, 5,   foot
wtr.tag.highway.steps =          1, 92, 5,   foot
wtr.tag.route.ferry =            2,  1, 10,  ferry
wtr.tag.route.shuttle_train =    2,  2, 50,  rail|car
wtr.tag.railway.rail =           3,  3, 50,  rail
```

Or is there some other mechanism for excluding them ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default config reflects a standard car-routing-topo. Hence it should not take footways or sth. similar into account. `finalMask=car` means that only ways which are drivable will be included and converted. But be careful. Paths or tracks and even ferries may be tagged with `motorcar=yes`. This indicates an alternative potential type of transport for cars where normal streets are not present.
The corresponding line in the config which influences this is this here:

```
wtr.allow.motor[car|_vehicle].[yes|destination] = car
```

So if you're only interested in "real" streets out-comment it.

Comment: Ok, so those bike, foot, and ferry records present are due to OSM listing them as motorcar=yes ?

Comment: usually footways are not tagged with motorcar=yes. So the amount of wrong streets you apparently receive may not be caused by this. Can you send me your `osm2po.config`?